# react - hostContainerInfo always null in IE11 Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, react-dom

We have a react application that is working perfectly fine on all browsers except IE11 (11.0.9). React Application won't even load on IE11 because in react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js @ line 405 hostContainerInfo is always null. While Chrome and firefox always gets proper value for hostContainerInfo.

```
mountComponent: function (transaction, hostParent, hostContainerInfo, context) {
this._rootNodeID = globalIdCounter++;
this._domID = hostContainerInfo._idCounter++;
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
Unable to get property '_idCounter' of undefined or null reference
```

Versions used:
react/react-dom: 15.4.1

Tried downgrading react to 15.3.2 and upgrading it 15.4.1, but the problem still exists.

Any guidance on how to approach this problem would be very helpful. Thanks.